# why linux-source-4.4.0 compiled to 4.4.79

Tags: kernel, compiling

I download `linux-source-4.4.0` through `apt-get`.

However when I compile and install the kernel source, the version becomes to be `4.4.79`.

However, there is no header files for `4.4.79` in apt repo.

How can I change it?

Comment: What would you like to change? would you like to have 4.4.0 kernel with header files? 4.4.79 kernel with header files? something else?

Comment: I want a kernel with version 4.4.0 and its header files, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you compile the kernel a wrong way.

If you run `make` you build a kernel non-Debian way and actually get a mainline kernel.

To get an Ubuntu kernel compile it by

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

And also if you build a custom kernel, you need to install custom headers.

Comment: thank you, I am new in kernel development. and I need a custom kernel for debug. following the courses online, I just `make menuconfig` to open kernel debug. and `make ` `make modules` `make modules_install` `make install` what should I do to get a custom kernel image with its header files. could you please offer me some websites about that? thank you so much.

Comment: what would happened if I just change the .`makefile` . I means I modify the `VERSION，PATCHLEVEL, SUBLEVEL, EXTRAVERSION`, then, make make modules and install them? that sounds stupid....

Comment: Nothing would happen, the version will change but it won't help you.

Comment: And I gave you commands to build a Debian kernel from source.

Comment: thank you! and can I  get the vmlinux and intrid files through this way?

Comment: thank you so much! I recompile the kernel using the method you provide and the website [ubuntu offical guid](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)